# Jitsi Picture in Picture(PiP) mode if I open app create new instance in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I have created the meeting app in flutter using the [jitsi_meet flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet) in that first I get the inputs from users like room name, display name, etc. After clicking on the button meeting get started when I press the home button it meeting go to PiP mode (Picture in Picture mode). When I am in pip mode I click on my flutter app it creates a new instance of the app and does not continue the meeting or go back to the meeting and the meeting is still running in pip mode. If I click on the pip screen it goes to the meeting but clicking on the app creates a new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the pip problem follow this [link](https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/issues/120#issuecomment-718800908) method to add pip in your jitsi meet app.